# How to remove #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax error in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Whenever I try to to run this function I get the following error message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that    corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END'   at line 10

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS regNum;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION regNum(i INT)
RETURNS CHAR(5)
 BEGIN
    RETURN CONCAT(
     CHAR(i / 26000 % 26 + 65), 
     CHAR(i / 1000 % 26 + 65), 
     CHAR(i / 100 % 10 + 48),
     CHAR(i / 10 % 10 + 48), 
     CHAR(i % 10 + 48))
 END;
 $$
 DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `;` after `end`, before it.

Since you change the delimiter from `;` to `$$`, the semicolon is not a delimiter any more (outside the function definition).

Just a special character and the DB engine does not know what to do with it and throws an error. You need to put it at the end of the `return` statement to end the statement inside the function.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS regNum;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION regNum(i INT)
RETURNS CHAR(5)
 BEGIN
    RETURN CONCAT(
     CHAR(i / 26000 % 26 + 65), 
     CHAR(i / 1000 % 26 + 65), 
     CHAR(i / 100 % 10 + 48),
     CHAR(i / 10 % 10 + 48), 
     CHAR(i % 10 + 48));
 END
 $$
 DELIMITER ;
```